# Button in ArcGIS add-in extension shows as "Missing"?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, add-in, python-addin

I do not understand why my add-in toolbar and button shows up as "Missing" when I open ArcMap. I am not sure whether this is an issue with ArcMap 10.3 or whether I did anything wrong. Have anyone ever encountered this before?

[image]

Comment: maybe it is because of the version 10.1 and 10.3. I am not sure. Whatever add-in I create on this computer will show up as "missing". But I found that creating the add-in on a different desktop solves the problem.

Comment: I saw this a few weeks ago and believe it was version related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this in the past - happened on half of our work PCs one day and we never did find the cause, however we did find a work-around.

Instead of loading our add-ins into the default location (My Documents I think) we set up Additional Add-In folders in ArcMap and copied our Add-In files there, and they work fine.  We didn't have to put all add-ins there, we found most worked, but the few that didn't worked fine with this work-around.

Open **Add-In Manager** from the Customize menu

[image]

Click the **Options** tab and **Add Folder** to point ArcMap at an alternative source for Add-In files.

[image]

For any Add-Ins that don't work, just find the esri-addin file and copy it into that new location.  I don't recall if the old one in My Documents had to be removed first, but that's an easy delete out of My Docs to get rid of it if required.

This even worked for Add-Ins that came with an installer that installed other files elsewhere - only the Add-In needed to be placed in the new folder, everything else still worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Usually I see this if the Windows environmental variables aren't set up correctly.

Try:

- Start command prompt (go to Start Menu ---> Run ---> type cmd)
- Type python, and then import arcpy (shown below is what you want to see)

Does everything work without errors?

[image]

---

If you get an error, then try:

- Right click on My Computer and go to Properties, then click on the
  Advanced system settings, and then on the Advanced tab click on the
  Environment Variables button at the bottom.
- Next, in the lower part of the window find the Variable that says
  Path and double click on it, and makes sure that the following paths
  are at the front of the Variable value list:

  ```
   C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Scripts;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib;
  ```

(Verify that these paths exist. Also, be sure to alter the 10.2 to your ArcGIS version.)

- Restart your computer. After restarting, try doing the python and
  import arcpy from the Command Prompt again.

[image]

---

Otherwise, it may be version related like @Chad Cooper suggested. This is pretty easy to fix. Open the *.esriaddin* file with 7zip, and then open the *config.xml* file.

[image]

In the *config.xml* file look for:

```
<Target name="Desktop" version="10.1" />
```

Change the version to match your current install. Save the edits to the *config.xml* file, and when it prompts if you'd like to update it in the archive, click OK.

Answer (score 0):

That happened with me because I wrote `import mapping`, which causes the error -
 there is no module called mapping

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I think this issue had something to do with 'spaces' in the path name - e.g. this caused a problem 'c:\arcgis\add in\' while this didn't cause a problem 'c:\arcgis\add_in\'